# I can't figure out how to call a function with a trigger, keeps saying function doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate(nr char) RETURNS char AS $$
    BEGIN

      RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patient_notitie WHERE pn_patient_nr = nr);

    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This worked:

```
SELECT * FROM calculate('100001');
```

This is where it went wrong, when we try to create the trigger to call the function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_calculate AFTER INSERT ON patient_notitie
EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate(pn_patient_nr);
```

It says the function doesn't exist:

> ERROR: function calculate() does not exist SQL state: 42883

Comment: What exactly should the trigger do? Your function only returns a single value what would be the sense in that as a trigger? (Unrelated, but: it should be defined as `returns integer` not `returns char` because it returns a number not a string)

Answer (score 2):

Before creating trigger, you need to create a trigger function, which has to be ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)):

> A user-supplied function that is declared as taking no arguments and returning type `trigger`

Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_t_f()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
...
-- do something
-- maybe with with calculate(char)...
...
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then you can create your trigger with that trigger function (not your original function):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_calculate
AFTER INSERT ON patient_notitie
EXECUTE PROCEDURE calculate_t_f();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that your two objects are created in different schemas:

If the function is created in `SCHEMA1.CALCULATE(char)` but the table is created in `SCHEMA2.TABLE1` .. the trigger will execute from `SCHEMA2`, which will not have visibility into `SCHEMA1` unless you `GRANT` it.

Also, leapfrogging off of a_horse_with_no_name's comment .. it sounds like you don't simply want to execute the function, but actually DO SOMETHING with the result...  If that's the case, you'd want to actually write a full fledged PLSQL code block for your trigger.

```
DECLARE
  my_nr_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(:NEW.nr) INTO my_nr_count FROM DUAL;
  :NEW.nr_count := my_nr_count;
  RETURN :NEW;
END;
```

Or something along those lines..